Do full BBGKY equations predict increase of entropy?
It can be shown, using the Liouville theorem, that a system performing Hamiltonian evolution does not increase its entropy (e.g., see What maximizes entropy?.) BBGKY hierarchy seems to be just an alternative way of describing Hamiltonian evolution, so I expect that it produces the same prediction...
On the other hand, Boltzmann H-theorem does predict entropy increase on the basis of the Boltzmann equation, obtained by truncating BBGKY hierarchy.
The question is essentially: is the H-theorem a consequence of truncating the hierarchy of equations, or is there some difference between the Liouville and BBGKY description of Hamiltonian evolution, which results in entropy increasing (in BBGKY)?

When discussing entropy in mathematical contexts, it helps to use precise terms. There are many different kinds of entropy, and their (approximate) equivalence or correspondence in statistical mechanical contexts is usually a non-obvious consequence of concentration of measure in high dimensions.  Heuristically, it depends on whether your entropy measure is a quantifier of uncertainty (w.r.t. some model) or a simple proxy for such a quantifier (e.g. usually an integral of some proxy for specific heat.)

@TLDR the linked post has the precise definition for which the claim is valid.

The Liouville equation and the BBGKY hierarchy are strictly equivalent. You therefore do not get an increase in entropy in either case. When you close the BBGKY at first order to get the Boltzmann equation, you invoke Stosszahlansatz which breaks time reversal symmetry hence the H-theorem. You can find a detailed discussion in Dorfman's An Introduction to Chaos in
Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics for example.
